# How to look up information based Azure AD User in ASP.NET Core MVC App

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I use Azure Authentication in ASP.NET Core MVC and would like to lookup information based on this and use it in the whole app.

Edit:
What I basically want can be described as follows:

1. Users logs in with Azure Auth
2. The app extracts the `preferred_username`
3. An object is created that uses `preferred_username` to look up more information from the database
4. this object can be used for DI in order to
5. create `IAuthorizationRequirement` in order to use `[Authorize(Policy = ("IsRequirementBasedOnLookedUpInformation"))]`
6. can be uses in the views, for example to hide html code in razor like this  `@if (Object.IsRequirementBasedOnLookedUpInformation)`

End Edit

Authentication is set up like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureB2C"));
```

This allows me to use the `ClaimsPrincipal User` throughout the whole application.

Now I want to look up some information in a database and make it available for the whole app.

```
public class UserWithPhoneNummer (dbContext _dbc, ClaimsPrincipal cp)
{
    // do stuff with cp.Identity.Name aso   
}
```

Then I would like to inject it via DI in a controller like this

```
public CashFlowAnalysisController(dbContext _dbc, UserWithPhoneNummer _uwpn)
{
    dbc = _dbc;
    uwpn = _uwpn;
}
```

I've found plenty of tutorials and guides, but these all aim at scenarios with EF Core and sophisticated user management.

When I try the `IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory` I get an error:

```
    services.AddScoped<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<mvcUser>,UserClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
```

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Mvc.Models.mvcUser]' while attempting to activate 'Mvc.Authorization.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory'.

I am happy to share more code, if needed and would be grateful for any pointers on how to achieve this.

Comment: Did you mean, you would like to search information of users what you have got from `azure ad` now you would like to find maching informtion from your local database? As per your error, your local app structured by `Identity` right? So far I know `azure ad` structure for instnace, `UPN` has no mapping with `identity` so how would you be able to found? Did you set any custom mappings or anything?

Comment: Well, the only thing that is fixed is Azure Authentication - the `Identity` comes from a tutorial I saw. I'll update the question to make it more clear what I want to achieve